# Padding in union is present or not

Tags: c, struct, padding, unions

Hello all,
I want to know whether **union uses padding?**
since the size of union is the largest data member size, can there be padding at the end?

Comment: In short, **Yes**!!On my Windows system, a union is padded to have a size that is a multiple of the size of an `int`,ie **4 bytes**.So unless you use `#pragma pack(1)`, a union having size 3 bytes will be padded with one more byte to yield 4 bytes.Write a program and try it before posting questions.

Comment: "a union is padded to have a size that is a multiple of the size of an int,ie 4 bytes." but in this case   
union ab{
    char a;
}a;
the size is 1

Comment: In your case there is no padding at all.Who said `padding` is always done?Like Daniel Fischer said,it is not **mandated**  by the standard.

Comment: `union u{unsigned a:21;};` - This union is 4 bytes on my Windows system unless I use `#pragma pack(1)`,3 bytes if I use it.

Answer (score 16):

> since the size of union is the largest data member size

That need not be true. Consider

```
union Pad {
    char arr[sizeof (double) + 1];
    double d;
};
```

The largest member of that union is `arr`. But usually, a `double` will be aligned on a multiple of four or eight bytes (depends on architecture and size of `double`). On some architectures, that is even necessary since they don't support unaligned reads at all.

So `sizeof (union Pad)` is usually larger than `sizeof (double) + 1` [typically `16 = 2 * sizeof (double)` on 64-bit systems, and either 16 or 12 on 32-bit systems (on a 32-bit system with 8-bit `char` and 64-bit `double`, the required alignment for `double` may still be only four bytes)].

That means there must then be padding in the union, and that can only be placed at the end.

Generally, the size of a `union` will be the smallest multiple of the largest alignment required by any member that is not smaller than the largest member.

Comment: but when we have char arr[sizeof(double)+1] alone in union its just gives size: 9?

Comment: That's not mandated by the standard, an implementation is allowed to add padding, but in general (with 8-byte `double`s), yes, that would give a size of 9.

Comment: Did anyone manage to show that this example will pad up? - asking because I don't think there is _any_ reason to pad here, its not as if there needs to be space between the two members, it should just pick the largest one.

Comment: @ideasman42 You can check whether your compiler inserts padding by writing and running a small programme printing out the sizes of `double` and `union Pad`.  I get that the size of the union is twice the size of `double` (16 = 2*8) on a 64-bit system from both gcc and clang [as expected]. The reason for padding is alignment (both align `double` on eight-byte boundaries).

Comment: Interesting, it **does** align, however if `double d` is replaced with `char d[sizeof(double)]`, then the union isn't padded. (linux/gcc at least)

Comment: @ideasman42 Yes, since the alignment of `char` is 1. If you use `int d[2]`, you will probably get 12 as the size since `int` more often than not is four bytes with four byte alignment nowadays. (Except perhaps on embedded systems where it may be two bytes often.)

Answer (score -2):

Union when we use with primitive types inside it

```
union
{
    char c;
    int x;
}
```

It seems like it doesn't use padding because the largest size data is anyway is aligned to boundary.

But when we nest a structure within union it does.

```
    union u
    {
        struct ss
        {
            char s;
            int v;
        }xx;
    }xu;
```

It resulted in size 8.

so answer for your question is PADDING is persent in UNION.

Comment: As Daniel suggested this is wrong. You are referring padding of struct as padding of union which is misleading.